# Call Api with Alamofire and store data into Coredata

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data, alamofire

i have class to manage database in which i have make function to update the data into particular entity but when i call api with pagination this one give me 50 data in every call and after getting data i update those data into my table but at that time UI freezing due to perform this all task into main queue i have seen many solution but not getting exactly idea to how can i do this by not disturbing to UI task into background queue and all.

so why i need this all process into background queue even not disturbing to UI Task and also work if my app go into background mode.

In My App Delegate File :-

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Name")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext (completionBlock: @escaping ((Bool) -> ())) {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
            completionBlock (true)
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            completionBlock (false)
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

In My database manager i have this function to save data into coredata :-

```
 func addUpdateState(stateArray: [StateInfo], completionBlock: @escaping ((Bool) -> ())) {
    let localStateArray = self.getStatesData()
    for state in stateArray {
        let isContained = localStateArray.contains(where: {$0.id == state.id})

        var stateDetail = StateMO()
        if isContained == false {
            //ADD STATE DATA
            if let stateEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: self.STATE_ENTITY, in: context) {
                stateDetail = NSManagedObject (entity: stateEntity, insertInto: context) as! StateMO
            }
        } else {
            //UPDATE STATE DATA
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: self.STATE_ENTITY)
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", state.id ?? "")
            do {
                let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                if results.count != 0 {
                    stateDetail = results.first as! StateMO
                }
            } catch {

            }
        }
        stateDetail.id = state.id
        stateDetail.state_name = state.stateName
        stateDetail.state_code = state.statecode
        stateDetail.createdAt = state.createdAt
        stateDetail.updatedAt = state.updatedAt
    }
    APP_DELEGATE.saveContext { result in
        completionBlock (result)
    }
}
```

My Api Manager Function to get data from server with alamofire request :-

```
func SyncStateList(with params: [String: Any], success: @escaping (_ result: Bool, _ message:String, _ response: [String: AnyObject]) -> () ,failure: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    let url = URLUtility.getURL(apiKey: ApiEndPoint.syncState)
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "token": currentUser?.token ?? ""
    ]
    if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet(){
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            if response.response?.statusCode == 401
            {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                showAlertMessage(title: self.unauthorizedMessage, "") {
                    LogoutClearEntireData()
                }
            } else if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                if let json = response.value {
                    if let response = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if response.success == true {
                            success(response.success,response.message,response)
                        } else {
                            success(false,response.message,response)
                        }
                    } else {
                        failure(response.error)
                    }
                } else {
                    failure(response.error)
                }
            } else {
                failure(response.error)
            }
        }.responseString { (responseString) in
            printLog(responseString.description)
        }
    } else {
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        showAlertMessage(title: "Unable to connect.", "Please check your internet connection.", complition: nil)
    }
}
```

Call Function to get all states data with pagination and store into coredata when start syncing by calling this function :-

```
func SyncStateList(completionBlock: @escaping ((_ success:Bool) -> ())) {
    let params: [String: Any] = ["date": lastModifiedDateForSyncState]
    APIManager.shared.SyncStateList(with: params) { success, message, response in
        if success == true {
            if let dataResponse = response["data"] as? [String: Any] {
                if let stateData = StateResponse(JSON: dataResponse) {
                    self.stateData = stateData
                }
            }
            lastModifiedDateForSyncState = self.stateData?.lastModifiedDate ?? ""
            if self.stateData?.isMoreRecordAvalilable == 1 {
                DatabaseManager.shareInstance.addUpdateState(stateArray: self.stateData?.states ?? []) { result in
                    self.SyncStateList(completionBlock: completionBlock)
                }
            } else {
                if self.stateData?.states.count != 0 {
                    DatabaseManager.shareInstance.addUpdateState(stateArray: self.stateData?.states ?? []) { result in
                        completionBlock(true)
                    }
                } else {
                    completionBlock(true)
                }
            }
        } else {
            printLog(message)
            completionBlock(false)
        }
    } failure: { error in
        printLog(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        completionBlock(false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still needs help with a similar issue. In my project, UI was frozen when the app was downloading the parts of data and updating the CoreData objects. Hopefully, the '[Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html)' was pretty helpful!

In the pceudo code snippet on the bottom you can see the `fetchHistory()` method uses the original context that should be accessed from UI thread only. The second function `downloadAudioAndUpdateDB()` downloads parts of items and updates CoreData object in background.

```
class PersistenceController: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var savedEntities: [MyDataModel] = []

    func fetchHistory() {
         let request = NSFetchRequest<MyEntity>(entityName: "MyEntity")
         request.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ MyEntity.start_epoch, ascending: false)
         ]

         do {
             let newEntities = try container.viewContext.fetch(request).map({ myEntity in
            MyDataModel(response: myEntity) })

            self.savedEntities = newEntities
         } catch let error {
            print("error fetching: \(error)")
         }
     }
     
     func downloadAudioAndUpdateDB(items: [MyDataModel], viewModel: ViewModel, updateUI: @escaping () -> Void) {
         let async_container = self.container
         async_container.performBackgroundTask() { (async_context) in
            items.forEach { _item in
                viewModel.downloadFile(fileName: _item.file_name) { path, error in
                    if let localPath = path {
                        let updateItem = _item.withLocalAudioPath(localAudioPath: localPath)
                        let request: NSFetchRequest<MyEntity> = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
                        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "item_id == %@", updateItem.item_id)
                        do {
                            if let recordToUpdate = try async_context.fetch(request).first {
                                recordToUpdate.localAudioPath = updateItem.localAudioPath

                                if async_context.hasChanges {
                                    do {
                                        try async_context.save()
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                           updateUI()
                                        }
                                    } catch {
                                        let nsError = error as NSError
                                        fatalError("Unresolved error saveData \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch let error {
                            print("error updateRecord: \(error)")
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the `performBackgroundTask()` provides the new CoreData context (`async_context`) that can safely operate in the background thread. If you want to update UI, e.g., to show the download progress, you can hoist each event through the `updateUI` lambda to the main thread.

```
    private func downloadNext() {
       let toDownload: [MyDataModel] = persistence.savedEntities.filter({ model in
          model.localAudioPath.isStringNullOrEmpty()
       })
       persistence.downloadAudioAndUpdateDB(items: toDownload, viewModel: viewModel) {
        persistence.fetchHistory()
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To me it's not very clear if you're calling those methods in a main thread or not, also if you have a big data set it could freeze the UI which might be the case.

So what I suggest is do your CoreData operations in a background thread and update UI in the main thread.

```
func addUpdateState(stateArray: [StateInfo], completionBlock: @escaping ((Bool) -> ())) {
    
    DispatchQueue.global().async { // sent to background
        
        let localStateArray = self.getStatesData()
        for state in stateArray {
            let isContained = localStateArray.contains(where: {$0.id == state.id})
            
            var stateDetail = StateMO()
            if isContained == false {
                //ADD STATE DATA
                if let stateEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: self.STATE_ENTITY, in: context) {
                    stateDetail = NSManagedObject (entity: stateEntity, insertInto: context) as! StateMO
                }
            } else {
                //UPDATE STATE DATA
                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: self.STATE_ENTITY)
                fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", state.id ?? "")
                do {
                    let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    if results.count != 0 {
                        stateDetail = results.first as! StateMO
                    }
                } catch {
                    // should handle this error here !!!
                }
            }
            stateDetail.id = state.id
            stateDetail.state_name = state.stateName
            stateDetail.state_code = state.statecode
            stateDetail.createdAt = state.createdAt
            stateDetail.updatedAt = state.updatedAt
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // APP_DELEGATE should be handled in the main thread
        // also it would be a better practice to create a separate class instead of keeping this in the AppDelegate.
                APP_DELEGATE.saveContext { result in
                    completionBlock (result)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: `NSManagedObjectContext` is not thread safe and must be used only on the same queue it was created on. It's a programmer error to use the same context on two different queues. If you only have a `viewContext` which is meant to be only used on the main queue, use the persistent container's [performBackgroundTask(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640564-performbackgroundtask) method instead.

Comment: this one is not work for me my app crashing when get data of states and also i rewrite the question what i need to perfectly